# Drop down that instantly switches info

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

I am looking to write an html page that has a drop down menu on it and some content. For instance, a drop down menu that has the seven days of the week listed and depending which day is selected a div contains that day's activities. I know how to make this work so that you can pick the day you want, press a button, and then the browser loads a new page with the desired info. How would I go about writing it so that as soon as the user clicks on the drop down menu entry the page's info alters. I was thinking that maybe I could store the info in a bunch of hidden divs that, upon clicking on the drop down menu's entry, could be swapped in and out. I'm not sure, however, how to capture the event of an entry in a drop-down menu being selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I was thinking that maybe I could store the info in a bunch of hidden divs that, upon clicking on the drop down menu's entry, could be swapped in and out.

You can also use AJAX to load data.

> I'm not sure, however, how to capture the event of an entry in a drop-down menu being selected.

JavaScript has lots of events: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp

I've done poor example using divs:

```
<html>
<body>

<select id="day">
  <option>Mon</option>
  <option>Tue</option>
  <option>Wed</option>
  <option>Thu</option>
  <option>Fri</option>
  <option>Sat</option>
  <option>Sun</option>
</select>

<div id="Mon">Mon contents</div>
<div id="Tue" style="display: none;">Tue contents</div>
<div id="Wed" style="display: none;">Wed contents</div>
<div id="Thu" style="display: none;">Thu contents</div>
<div id="Fri" style="display: none;">Fri contents</div>
<div id="Sat" style="display: none;">Sat contents</div>
<div id="Sun" style="display: none;">Sun contents</div>

<script>
 var day = document.getElementById ( "day" );  
 var current_day = day.value;

 function change_day ()
 {
   document.getElementById(current_day).style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById(day.value).style.display = "block";
   current_day = day.value;
 }

 day.addEventListener("change", change_day);  

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This looks quite promising but the event listener doesn't seem to be getting triggered.

Comment: Figured it out, I changed the javascript from having the addEventListener() to just adding an onchange event directly to the select tag. Thanks!

Comment: `event listener doesn't seem to be getting triggered` Do you use Internet Explorer? IE needs `day.attachEvent("onchange", change_day);"`

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use jQuery to achieve some show/hide tricks if you have static data like this.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
  .hidden{ display:none; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <button>Toggle</button>
<div class="hideandshow">
    <div class="hidden" id="content1">Content 1</div>
    <div class="hidden" id="content3">Content 3</div>
    <div class="hidden" id="content4">Content 4</div>
</div>
<select id="select">
    <option value="">Select something to show</option>
    <option value="content1">Show Content 1</option>
    <option value="content3">Show Content 3</option>
    <option value="content4">Show Content 4</option>
</select>
<script>
$("#select").change(function () {
    $(".hideandshow div").hide();
    var divToShow = $("#select option:selected").val();
    if(divToShow == "")
        return;
    $("#" + divToShow).show();
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

If you take a look at the code, you can see I load jQuery to use function like, hide/show.
Everytime a change is triggered on the drop down list, all the div in the div with the class : "hideAndShow" are hidden. Right after that, I show the div that has been selected retrieving the selected value.